# How to format monthly data table into time series in python

Tags: python, time, formatting, series

table looks like this:

```
Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
```

Year

1948    3.4 3.8 4.0 3.9 3.5 3.6 3.6 3.9 3.8 3.7 3.8 4.0

1949    4.3 4.7 5.0 5.3 6.1 6.2 6.7 6.8 6.6 7.9 6.4 6.6

1950    6.5 6.4 6.3 5.8 5.5 5.4 5.0 4.5 4.4 4.2 4.2 4.3

1951    3.7 3.4 3.4 3.1 3.0 3.2 3.1 3.1 3.3 3.5 3.5 3.1

1952    3.2 3.1 2.9 2.9 3.0 3.0 3.2 3.4 3.1 3.0 2.8 2.7

I want the output to look like:

Date              Data

1948-01-01        0.034

1948-02-01        ....

etc

I tried this already:
[Convert monthly data table to seasonal time series using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959868/convert-monthly-data-table-to-seasonal-time-series-using-pandas)

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: I guess the result would look like what df.stack() would give my, only other concern would be how to set the index as proper datetime in time series manner.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
columns = pd.date_range(start = "1948", periods=12, freq='MS') 
columns = columns.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') #this is optional if you want to change format
print (columns)
```

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. That can reduce the number of follow-up questions, and  help new developers understand the underlying concepts. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?